# git push the whole local repository overwriting the remote one

Tags: git, http

I have an issue: while `git push`ing I've got an error:

```
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/tags/
  refs/heads/
updating 'refs/heads/master'
  from 5c797ac9a561aef9c1955ba7d3f566e9474454a7
  to   f57849e2e68454e22dcef2d73383e489e30e5b14
    sending 10 objects
PUT c757df860185122ff87c0009d4ead36aabbdd2a8 failed, aborting (22/400)
PUT a6c48f26df4fa29f4d68501bfed3901ba43fce26 failed, aborting (22/400)
^CRemoving remote locks...
```

Next `git push` has succeeded. But after that `git clone` start to warn that `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository`. I have the whole history safe at my local copy. Is there a way to push it to the remote server?

I've tried `git push -f` and `git push -f origin master` but none of them helped me.

Comment: Do those PUTs mean you're pushing over FTP? If an FTP PUT failed it's probably not Git's fault. Do you have a disk quota on the remote side? Funky permissions?

Comment: @Jefromi I'm pushing over HTTP. Ofcourse, it's most probably not git's fault, but that doesn't make me feel better. I'm not sure about any disk quota's, but I don't have full access to repository indeed, because it is maintained by University's administrator and I'm working on my course project (I am 6th year student).

Comment: @Jefromi For now, I figured out that some dummy commit resurrects my repository until next failure on `git push`.

Comment: Well, it's a good question. I don't really know how to diagnose it (I've never used Git's HTTP). From a quick look at the source, the 400 there is an HTTP 400 (bad request) error. (The 22 is just libcurl reporting that there was an HTTP error >= 400.) I'm not sure why Git would be sending a bad request, though.

Comment: What kind of HTTP is it? Webdav or "smart-HTTP" (using git on the server side)?

Comment: @ysdx As far as I know, it is a WebDAV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a "bare" checkout:

```
git clone --bare ./project ./project.git
```

and copy the project.git folder on the server (if you using a WebDav HTTP server).

Comment: Maybe I miss something obvious but for now I have no clue how to copy something to the server.

Comment: If our using a webdav server, you can use a webdav client in order to access it's files (as you would for FTP). Many file browsers can be used to access webdav (nautilus and other GVFS/GIO based programs, dolphin/konqueror and any other KDE KIO bases program, any Window based program by adding a "HTTP share").